# Can not set font family in init file in Windows

Tags: init-file, fonts

In my `.emacs` file I have the following:

```
(setq default_font "Office Code Pro D")
(when (member default_font (font-family-list))
  (set-face-attribute 'default nil
                      :family default_font
                      :font default_font))
```

After startup, if I evaluation the `(when...` function, my font family is set properly, but it is not set correctly when this file is sourced on startup.

After startup, if I check the value of `default_font` it is (correctly) `Office Code Pro D`, however, it does not set the font for my Emacs session unless I evaluate that part specifically.

Is there a reason why this does not get set in startup?

(Typically I run Emacs daemon on boot and this does not work).

Answer (score 3):

With a quick check with Emacs 24.4 when you have just an Emacs daemon running `font-family-list` is nil so your code does nothing at that point. You'd need to add your function to a hook that runs after you have a GUI window, for example `after-make-frame-hook`.

Alternatively, why not set the default font using Customize? There's a Set Default Font in the options menu by default which (after Save options, also in the options menu) sets the default font in your init file using `custom-set-faces`.

Comment: Great find.  I do not like to set the font using Customize on principle.  I like to know where I am setting my own variables.  Additionally, the font I am using is custom so it may not be installed on all systems, idk if Custom allows a hook to check for that.